# ORMLite issues when updating and refreshing entities with ForeignCollections

Tags: java, android, ormlite

I made sure to read the documentation a few times concerning this topic but I can't seem to wrap my head around it. I have a Model called `Home` that has a `ForeignCollection` of `Person`.

`Home.class`:

```
public class Home implements Serializable{

     @DatabaseField(id = true, canBeNull = false, columnName = "id")
     private long id;

     @ForeignCollectionField(eager = true, maxEagerLevel = 2)
     private Collection<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();

     //constructors, getters, and setters...
}
```

---

`Person.class`:

```
public class Person {
     @DatabaseField(id=true, canBeNull = false, columnName = "id")
     private long id;

     @DatabaseField(foreign = true, foreignAutoCreate = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true)
     private Home home;
     //constructors getters setters and other properties that are not important for this question
}
```

Now after initially inserting values into my `Home` and `Person` models, I was able to have something that looks like this:

**Home Object**:

```
{
     "id" : 1, 
     "persons" : [{"id" : 1}, {"id" : 2}, {"id" : 3}]
}
```

Now I don't want to update the contents of the `persons` field from the `Person` model. I just want to update the `Home` object's `persons` field.

I've tried the following :

```
home.setPersons(newArrayOfPersons); //this array is the same array except I removed one element.
homeDao.update(home);
```

The above code didn't throw any errors, but it didn't seem to be updating my SQLite database.

Then I tried using an `UpdateBuilder`:

```
 UpdateBuilder<Home, Long> updateBuilder = homeDao.updateBuilder();
 updateBuilder.where().eq("id", home.getId());
 updateBuilder.updateColumnValue("persons", newArrayOfPersons);
 updateBuilder.update();
 homeDao.refresh(home);
```

Unfortunately, this one threw me exceptions about how I can't update a field that is a Foreign Collection.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I actually had some food to eat today which may probably have a direct correlation to why I was able to solve this issue. The documentation made more sense this morning after having breakfast and it turns out I was doing it all wrong. Since the `Person` is a foreign collection of `Home`, it's maintaining a foreign key that maps back to the parent...so I did an update on the Foreign collection instead and VOILA!

**Instead of doing this:**

```
 UpdateBuilder<Home, Long> updateBuilder = homeDao.updateBuilder();
 updateBuilder.where().eq("id", home.getId());
 updateBuilder.updateColumnValue("persons", newArrayOfPersons);
 updateBuilder.update();
 homeDao.refresh(home);
```

**I did this instead:**

```
UpdateBuilder<Person, Long> updateBuilder = personDao.updateBuilder();
updateBuilder.where().in("id", arrayOfIdsOfPersons); //I just got all the ids of each object I want to update
updateBuilder.updateColumnValue("home_id", secondHome); //changed the mapping to point to another `Home Object`
updateBuilder.update();

homeDao.refresh(secondHome); //not sure if I need this one though.
```

Also, I had to modify the annotation of my childs properties that specified the foreign key to my parents model and added the `columnName = "home_id"`

Hope this makes sense and helps anyone out in the future.